# I want my ps1 file to insert "<" but it errors

Tags: powershell, replace

Operating on powershell 1.0, I'm writing a powershell script to replace text of an aspx file. When it gets to my second `<`  it gives me an error:

```
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
```

An equivalent code example is:

```
ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "<title>Welcome!</title>","<title>Welcome! Warning...</title>"
```

How do I fix it so I can insert the `<`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `<` outside of a quoted string?  Having `<` inside a quoted string should be fine.  Well except for string that are regex patterns as `<` is a metacharacter.

Comment: have you closed the loop `}`